# Does General Relativity satisfy the Homotopy (or “h”) Principle?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematics, topology, differential-equations

By this I mean in the standard second order (whether metric or tetrad/verbein-based) form of General Relativity. I've been reading about the [homotopy principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_principle)  of late (see Eliashberg's *introduction to the h-principle* for a good intro or Gromov's *Partial Differential Relations* for an in-depth look).

Basically one takes an $r$th order partial differential relation PDR (i.e. the Einstein-Hilbert action or it's ensuing field equation), and considers each derivative as an independent variable/coordinate on a larger Jet bundle effectively turning a differential relation into an algebraic one on a larger manifold. This can also be considered as turning a problem in differential topology into a problem in algebraic topology.

In order to do this the PDR must satisfy the h-principle. I'm relatively new to this idea and would like to know if the Einstein-Hilbert action satisfies it. To satisfy the h-principle one has to show that any solution to the algebraic problem on the Jet-bundle can be deformed via a homotopy to a genuine solution to the problem at hand. I'm sure someone has figured this out already, and knows the answer.

I should point out that, from what I can tell, the first order Palanti formulation is precisely a first-order application of the h-principle to the Einstein-Hilbert action (albeit an incomplete one as the EH action is second order!).

Remember wondering why we could vary w.r.t the connection as though it was an independent variable? The h-principle is why you can do that (but only in some cases).